# Foreach Control in Form

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I have a lot of `SimpleButton` (DevExpress Controls) in my form.  I want to set `AllowFocus` to `false` for them through code.

```
foreach (Control x in this.Controls)
{
    if (x is SimpleButton)
    {
        ((SimpleButton)x).AllowFocus = false;
    }
}
```

Nothing really happen when I use this code.  It still allow focus.

Comment: Are the SimpleButtons added directly to the Form, or are they maybe added to a Panel or other container Control (TabPage for example) ?

Comment: Please check whether the innermost statement is actually executed.

Comment: in GroupControl , and GroupControl is in XtraTabPage , yea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your comment, it is clear that SImpleButton objects are not directly on the Form, so iterating the Form's Controls collection is not going to return those.

You need to iterate the GroupControl's Controls collection.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

**Solved :**

```
 foreach (Control x in groupControl1.Controls)
        {
            if (x is SimpleButton)
            {
                ((SimpleButton)x).AllowFocus = false;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

```
var buttons = this.Controls.OfType<Control>()
    .SelectMany(x => x.Controls.OfType<SimpleButton>());

foreach(var button in buttons)
      button.AllowFocus = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest better to have Re-cursive function, I generally place all controls in main container panel, and you just need pass that container to Function, rest of things function will do for you.

```
private void FocusControls(Control ctl)
        {
             if ((ctl.GetType() == typeof(GroupBox)) ||
                    (ctl.GetType() == typeof(DevExpress.XtraEditors.GroupControl)) ||
                    (ctl.GetType() == typeof(DevExpress.XtraEditors.PanelControl)) ||
                    (ctl.GetType() == typeof(DevExpress.XtraTab.XtraTabControl)) ||
                    (ctl.GetType() == typeof(DevExpress.XtraTab.XtraTabPage))
                    )
                {                    
                    foreach (Control obj in ctl.Controls)
                        FocusControls(obj);
                }
                 if (ctl.GetType() == typeof(SimpleButton))
                    {
                        SimpleButton objTemp = (SimpleButton)ctl;   
                        objTemp.AllowFocus = false;
                    }
        }
```

Answer (score -3):

Might just be a case of checking the types: 
if (typeof(x) == typeof(SimpleButton))

Comment: And what do you think `if (x is SimpleButton)` is doing ?